# Is it considered "bad practice" to instantiate a subclass by calling a method from the parent?

Tags: python, oop

I working on a "file-converter" that needs to read in data-files and convert them to .h5 files. The data-files have very different layout/structure so I am trying to follow OOP principles to the best of my knowledge. My question is if it is considered bad practice for me to call a method in the base class "get_class()" that would determine what kind of subclass should be instantiated based on the data-file structure?

Comment: A parent should know nothing of its children. You probably want an independent factory function/class instead.

Comment: I disagree with @deceze here. Having an independent factory creates an unnecessary mess. I don't see anything wrong with defining that factory directly in your base class.

Comment: Suppose this makes this question *opinion based*…

Comment: Please post an example, or a class diagram of what you have in mind.